# Domain model property to DTO

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, single-page-application

Using DDD, if I have something like this in my domain model:

```
public class OrderLineItem {
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal LineTotal { get { return UnitPrice * Quantity; } }
}
```

The dto can have a property for the LineTotal as `public decimal LineTotal { get; set; }` which is fine.

Let's say I now created a UI as an SPA. If I want to display the line total as I add the line item with a quantity to an order, would I need to recreate the calculation in my dto/ViewModel/client side or can I move the calculation that's in the domain model to a service(?) and call it from my SPA? That seems more logical but I'm not sure how/where to code it. If anyone could point me to an example that would really help.

Comment: Why use DTO? Domain model should be used for command side. Why don't you try calculating line total when a line is added and then store total? Then you can read it any way you like.
What I'm trying to say is that you can have two models, one for the command side (domain model), and one for the read side i.e. CQRS.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Are you saying to add the same calculation to the domain and the "UI" model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A domain model is used when you are trying to execute some piece of business logic. For example, when adding new OrderLineItem you'll probably check if some business requirements are met e.g. the total of all OrderLineItems cannot be greater than N, or OrderLineItem Quantity must be min N.

Also, you can store calculated LineTotal. There is no need to calculate it again and again. You don't want your customers to be shown different LineTotal after they put an item in the basket.

When fetching that same OrderLineItem to show it on UI there is no need going through all that business rules because they've been already checked.
So you can use a separate model that'll map directly to your table (or service model etc).

I recommend reading more on CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation) and how it fits with DDD.

After rereading your question I see I didn't answer your question in full.
As I see it you have at least two paths both of which include using domain model at some point.

You can handle adding OrderLineItem completely in front-end with calculating Total by calling some piece of code in the backend. We can call that piece of code Domain Service. After all OrderLineItems are added and you want to persist them, you add them using domain model which checks business rules. There is a possibility you'll have to duplicate some of the business logic because of UI requirements. That is inevitable.

The second approach is a variation of first where you use domain model immediately after OrderLineItem is added. In that way, Total is calculated and returned using the approach I described in the first couple of paragraphs. All business rules are checked immediately also.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you for the explanation!